# How to call Exit Command when I press Key # in Lwuit Mobile Application?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form, lwuit-command

Can I assign the `Exit` Command to the <kbd>#</kbd> key in an Lwuit Application? When I press the key <kbd>#</kbd>, the `Exit` command should be called automatically and exit the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should listen for a KeyPress or keyReleased event on the form with the keycode for # and exitApplication when the # key is pressed.

```
protected void keyPressed(int key)
{
    System.out.println("Key Pressed");

    if(key==52) //change 52 to match keyCode for # key 
    {
      Display.getInstance().exitApplication();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by calling a command like open, close? You can execute any code you want after getting the keyPressed/keyReleased event in the code braces {}.