# how to call a command while pressing key # in Lwuit Midlet?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call Exit Command when I press Key # in Lwuit Mobile Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834441/how-to-call-exit-command-when-i-press-key-in-lwuit-mobile-application)

How Can I Call Command like **SELECT**, **OPEN** when I press Key <kbd>#</kbd> in LWUIT MIDLET Mobile Application.

Comment: answer is essentially the same as in your prior question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834441/how-to-call-exit-command-when-i-press-key-in-lwuit-mobile-application for that matter, the question is essentially the same, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture the press of the key using `Canvas.KEY_POUND` and do the action what you want to do.